# me/feed with pic from different domain

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-c#-sdk

I was trying to find this on facebook's site in their documentation but so far no luck.  I'm sure others must have run into this before.

I use Amazon S3 for storing images.  I didn't know ahead of time that if I named my bucket as my domain name with subdomain I could link that way, so until I move all of the pictures I have to link to mybucket.s3.amazonaws.com domain.  When I include a picture from there with a post to the wall the picture doesn't show up.  If I change the picture to one on the server itself the picture does show up.  It seems that the domain name of the picture must match my app?  I looked at bugzilla and didn't see this mentioned.  Facebook's forum says to post questions here.

I'm using the C# Facebook SDK from CodePlex.

My code looks like (with error handling and authentication check removed):

```
        var client = new FacebookClient(FACEBOOK_APP_ID, FACEBOOK_SECRET);
        client.AccessToken = facebook.AccessToken;
        var parameters = new Dictionary<string, object>();
    parameters.Add("name", name);
        parameters.Add("caption", title);
        parameters.Add("message", message);
        parameters.Add("link", link);
        parameters.Add("source", link);
        parameters.Add("picture", imageUrl);
        client.Post("me/feed", parameters);
```

I verified that imageUrl does indeed have a correct picture, the domain name just doesn't match.  The picture on amazon s3 has public read access.  I can view it from my browser so I don't think it's a permission problem.  I've tried a few different pictures with the same problem.  Only time it's worked so far is when the picture was on the server itself.

So, my question is, is it a problem with me, or does facebook block images that don't match the domain name specified on the app?

Comment: Same issues found when sharing through iOS Device

Answer (score 4):

You can upload the picture from that url, then add its object id in the post.

*Refer to*: http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/526/?ref=nf

**Uploading Photos to the Graph API via a URL**

> Earlier this year, we released support for uploading photos directly
>   via the Graph API. This requires sending the photo as a MIME-encoded
>   form field. We are now enhancing our photo upload capability by
>   introducing the ability to upload photos simply by providing a URL to
>   the image. This simplifies photo management for a number of use cases:
>
> - App developers who host their images on Amazon S3 or a similar
>     service can pass the S3 URL directly to Facebook without having to
>     download the file to their application servers only to upload it
>     again to Facebook. This improves performance and reduces costs for
>     developers.
> - Apps written on platforms that don't have good support for
>     multipart    file uploads can create new photos more easily.
>
> To upload a photo via a URL, simply issue an HTTP POST to
>   ALBUM_ID/photos with the url field set to the URL of the photo you
>   wish to upload. You need the publish_stream permission to perform this
>   operation. You can also include an optional message parameter to set a
>   caption for the photo.

Comment: So it would add the picture to the users album? That's not what I want.  This is just for when a user comments on a picture. It's supposed to show the thumbnail, their comment, a description of the picture, and a link to the picture.  Not actually add it to their album.

Comment: You should be able to use the same method to upload to your Page or App.  For a page upload you will need to generate an access_token for page, and same for app.

Comment: REViSE - user must be owner of photo.  You will need to upload the photo as the user to your wall photos, "if it is possible".  I will try to get a working sample of this going and post back if i am successful.

Comment: I don't want any picture uploaded.  It worked for a picture on my server that wasn't uploaded, just by providing the image URL.  It didn't add the picture to my album (I was the user) and I saw the thumbnail.

Answer (score 4):

I'am facing the same issue as well. Based on my observations it seems that facebook does not like it when the picture url has more than one sub-domain.

I tried the below 2 URL variations for the same image..

**mybucket.s3.amazonaws.com** - throws an error

**s3.amazonaws.com/mybucket** - works fine

```
:picture => 'http://mybucket.s3.amazonaws.com/footprints/15/coverimgs/medium.jpg'
OAuthException: (#100) picture URL is not properly formatted

:picture => 'http://s3.amazonaws.com/mybucket/footprints/15/coverimgs/medium.jpg'
{"id"=>"587472956_10150280873767957"}
```

Now i have to figure out how to change the URL structure for the image while passing it to the FB graph API.

Answer (score 0):

I would [log it as a bug](http://bugs.developers.facebook.net).  If this is really the case, which I kinda doubt, you could create a 301 redirect on your own domain for each image that redirects to the Amazon url.